# How to make realistic shot in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm just wondering how to make shots in my game more realistic. I mean there are two main ways in implementing shots. First: throw a small projectile and let it detect collisions. Second: use raycast. But in real world (and apparently I noticed this in PUBG) bullets fly really quick but not immediately. Here is why you should aim near your target if it's far away from you to hit it. Because if you aim right where it is it will move and your bullet will miss the target.

I'm just curious if any of you, guys have a nice solution to this problem. Also I wish to find a way to use raycast not every frame. In such things like detecting if you will actually hit the wall when shooting. If you have any good ideas how to implement spread and recoil for different types of weapons I will be happy to read them.

Comment: I Think the bullet fly path is like a curve , maybe like a ball it is will slow down , so maybe need to google "bullet physics"

Comment: Not eazy to say just use raycast or collsions. it's more complex

Comment: @TimChang Units has an NVidia Physics engine ... so why not use it?

Comment: @derHugo Maybe it's too expensive? because too many bullet in one game. bullet is a point not a ball don't need use collider. maybe just write a pure bullet system is better. but NVidia Physics maybe do this well, I'am not familiar with this package

Comment: NVidia is the underlying engine of `Physics` so anything using Colliders and Rigidbody.. and it depends .. if OP wants a `realistic` shot it would be a sphere/capsule moving on a parabola path and need to check if it hits anything which might be easy using built-in physics

Comment: @derHugo for `realistic` I agree you

Comment: @derHugo but when bullet too fast , How it's work. the bullet can pass the human ?

Comment: Why should it pass the human? The physics engine will calculate and register a collision...

Comment: @derHugo, Because of clipping. It just renders in frame in front of the obstacle and in the next frame - behind it. Unity supports different collision detection methods but I still more like raycasts for this kind of problems.

Comment: @TimChang bullet uses ballistic trajectory as any physical object but it has very little mass and moves at really high velocity. I mean you can't just curve and delay the Raycast.

Comment: @KuzmychMaksym as said if you use it correctly the physics should already cover that as well and calculate also the collisions that happen in between two frames. Instead of a raycast you could also use a sphere cast and allow a bit of a range around your actual target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blue point is bullet point of frame. and in very frame send a new raycast to check cross any human. like red line in this picture.
and bullet path use unity built-in Physics system to do it.

[image]

Comment: This one seems to be a nice solution to my problem. Thank you for reply.